# Ctrl C/V/F/L shortcuts and super by itself no working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I updated to 20.04 yesterday and most of the time these shortcuts don't work with right control key. Left one works perfectly but right rarely works at all, even when I press it alone so it highlights the cursor. Super key also rarely responds when I press it by itself.

Everything was fine with Ubuntu 19.10

What can I do about this?

Update: this seems to be only the problem when I use non English keyboard layouts, but I still need those often :/

Answer (score 0):

You should press: Ctrl + Shift + [whatever] 
but not:  Shift + Ctrl + [the-same-thing]
[Ctrl+Shift working but not Shift+Ctrl in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232593/ctrlshift-working-but-not-shiftctrl-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts)