# Shift+Ctrl not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, I have noticed *any* shortcut involving both <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> does not work if I <kbd>Shift</kbd> before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. In other words, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not work but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> works. This is true whether I use Chrome, Firefox, VS code or any other software. Needless to say, this is frustrating and I never experienced such issue before 20.04. Is this intended or have I messed up something?

Comment: Do you have multiple keyboard layouts? If so, do you use <Shift>+<Ctrl> to switch between them?

Comment: @pomsky I am afraid, but it did not resolve the issue. If after pressing either of Shift key, I press left Ctrl, shortcut does not work. Nothing happens.

Comment: *What* did not resolve the issue? I did not even suggest a solution in the first place! I just asked a couple of questions in my [previous comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240036/shiftctrl-not-working#comment2089096_1240036).

Comment: @pomsky I am sorry for late reply and any confusion I might have caused, but I am still facing the issue I described in the above post. After you suggested to check my keyboard layout, I found out that I had only one layout. I fiddled with settings regardless, restarted Ubuntu and I thought that the issue had vanished, but it was only a misjudgement on my part. That issue is very much still present. If use my left Ctrl key in conjunction with any of the Shift keys, I must press Ctrl before the shift key.

Comment: This issue is here, I just understood today that the order of key pressing is important, but it's annoying my for about a week, since I installed ubuntu 20. Never happened before in any other OS

Comment: @BrunoLamps I relieved to know that I am not the only one to face the issue.

Comment: Looks like an update to Ubuntu has fixed this.

Comment: Sorry @lightsaber, just updated mine and the problem still exists. But I found a solution in here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232593/ctrlshift-working-but-not-shiftctrl-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts
In my case it was using ctrl to highligh the mouse position. When I shut if off, the problem disappears. Unfortunatelly I need this feature, it wasn't buggy in the past, but it seems like I'll be using ubuntu without it for a while.

Comment: @BrunoLamps I do not know how the issue got corrected on my system but I also had Locate Pointer enabled. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @BrunoLamps Yes, I had this same problem, and disabling Locate Pointer fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ctrl+Shift working but not Shift+Ctrl in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232593/ctrlshift-working-but-not-shiftctrl-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts)